# Laravel ORM: unique combination of fields from pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

This question extends the example  [Eloquent : Working With Pivot Tables](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) provided in the Laravel Documentation.

The relationship here is that a `User` has many `Role` objects that it can relate to, and each `Role` is made up of a number of `Task`'s.

The relationships between these models are:

**User and Role:**

- Each `Role` may only relate to one `User`, however a `User` may have many `Role`'s
- A *one-to-many* relationship

**Role and Task**

- Each `Role` can have many `Task`'s associated with it, and each `Task` can belong to several `Role`s
- A *many-to-many* relationship

In terms of a database schema (MySql), we therefore have:

- A `users` table that has no foreign keys
- A `roles` table with a `user_id` foreign key
- A `tasks` table
- A `role-task` pivot table

---

In plain English, the constraint I need to apply is that a user **can not** be associated with multiple roles that are made up of exactly the same tasks, however two role's **can** be made up of exactly the same task's

Is there an in-built way to apply this constraint using Laravels Eloquent ORM system? If not, what would be a tidy workaround?

---

## edit:

Eloquent-like description:

```
User hasMany Role
Role belongsToMany Task
```

Question: How to prevent assigning to a `user` multiple `roles` having exactly the same related collection of `tasks`

Comment: check the edit I made to your question - instead of that long and hard to read description use this two-liner and everything becomes clear (in the context of Eloquent ofc). Then, check if the question is what you really wanted. If so, let me know and I'll show you.

Comment: yep that's correct. cheers